# How to correctly use egen mean function for computing average differences of the time series?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I have the panel data in the format:
    | transaction_id | city_id | week | tr_cw |
, where tr_cw is some metric computed for each city for each week.

I'm trying to compute the mean growth of the metric for each city using egen:

```
egen tag_cw = tag(city_id week)
sort tag_cw city_id week
by tag_cw city_id: egen tr_speed = mean(tr_cw[_n]-(tr_cw[_n-1])) if tag_cw
```

However, the result is different from a bit more complicated computation (which numerically looks more valid):

```
by tag_cw city_id: g _tr_n = tr_cw[_n] if tag_cw
by tag_cw city_id: g _tr_n1 = tr_cw[_n-1] if tag_cw
by tag_cw city_id: egen tr_speed2 = mean(_tr_n-_tr_n1)
```

What am I missing in using egen? Is there a good tutorial to find out about the correct usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for `egen` is quite explicit:

"Explicit subscripting (using `_N` and `_n`), which is commonly used with `generate`, should not be used with `egen`"

The reason is that `egen` often changes the sort order temporarily to do what it does, so subscripts will not necessarily mean what you think.

So you need to create your own growth variable first and then use `egen`.

Simplifying your problem to one transaction for each city and week, and assuming no gaps in time within each panel and no missings, this should suffice:

```
bysort city_id (week) : gen tr_diff = tr_cw - tr_cw[_n-1] 
by city_id: egen tr_speed = mean(tr_diff) 
egen tag = tag(city_id) 
l city tr_speed if tag
```

You will need to complicate that for multiple transactions. You don't make clear how they are to be combined.

Comment: why week is in parentheses in "bysort city_id (week)"?

Comment: PS your solution assumes that city week uniquely identifies the observation, there are many transactions in each city each week, that's why I use "if tag" in egen

Comment: btw, it would be great if the compiler warns everyone who uses _n with egen

Comment: You are correct that I ignored your `transaction_id` variable. I have edited my answer to make that explicit. You probably need to `collapse` your data first so that there are unique observations for each city and week. Note that there is no Stata compiler; this is interpreted code. A Stata answer is that it would be great if users read the help.

Comment: Pablo's point about Stata trapping this is undoubtedly an interesting question. `egen` requests invoking `_n` and/or `_N` fall, at present, into the territory of legal syntax, but a bad idea, and the company's line is to warn you in the help, but not add extra code trapping it.

Answer (score 3):

Nick's answer should give you what you need,

To answer your follow up question of

> why week is in parentheses in "bysort city_id (week)"?

Is explained in the manual for `bysort`

to quote the manual...

> It verifies that the data are sorted by varlist1 varlist2 and then performs a by as if only varlist1 were specified